# SQL - Combine multiple column and apply ILIKE

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSql and I have `user` table with `firstName` and `lastName` column.
Please check below table as a example

```
----------------------------------------------------
id | firstname | lastName
----------------------------------------------------
1  | Keval     | Gangani
----------------------------------------------------
2  | New       | User
----------------------------------------------------
```

My pg query is `SELECT * FROM users WHERE ("firstname" ILIKE %Keval Gangani% OR "lastName" ILIKE %Keval Gangani%)` but this return zero results.

I know there is no records with `%Keval Gangani%`

I want to combine `firstName` and `lastName` and then i want to apply ILIKE query.

Comment: So then, just do so...?? `WHERE firstname + ' ' + lastname ILIKE '%Keval Gangani%'`, or similar. not clear why you need leading/trailing wildcards though

Comment: There are no first names like `%Keval Gangani%` or last names like `%Keval Gangani%`

Comment: @underscore_d can you write full query please. `WHERE firstname + ' ' + lastname ILIKE '%Keval Gangani%'` throwing `No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` error.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE concat(firstname,' ',lastName) ILIKE '%Keval Gangani%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE concat(firstname,' ',lastName) ILIKE '%Keval Gangani%'`

Thanks to [@Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14871018/philippe)